# "Mit" zusammen mit Plural dialektal in Akkusativ?

Tags: preposition, dialect

In Österrreich habe ich mehrmals die Präposition *mit* zusammen mit einem Präpositionalobjekt in Plural in Akkusativ gehört.

Z.B.

> Die Dame mit **die** Blumen braucht Hilfe.

Meine Fragen:

Ist das nur einfach ein Fehler? Habe ich doch mehrmals falsch gehört?
Wenn es aber Dialektal so gehört, wird es als ungebildet aufgefasst, sich so zu ausdrücken? Auf welchem Niveau wäre dies "erlaubt", mundartlich oder umgangssprachlich?

Comment: Das scheint im österreichischen (oder speziell im Wiener?) Dialekt gebräuchlich zu sein. Ich erinnere mich an den folgenden Satz aus der deutschen Synchronisation von "Der dritte Mann" (aus dem Gedächtnis zitiert): "Das hat man davon, wenn man freundlich ist zu die Ausländer!"

Comment: Das ist beim [Ruhrpott-Dativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruhrdeutsch) nicht viel anders.

Comment: @RHa, Danke, du hast wahrscheinlich recht, dass dies auch andere Dativpräpositionen zutrifft, z. B: "zu".

Comment: @IQV In den norddeutschen Dialekten würde ich die Ersetzung von Dativ durch Akkusativ eigentlich auch eher erwarten als in Österreich, weil im Niederdeutschen Dativ und Akkusativ anscheinend weitgehend zusammenfallen.

Comment: Das ist - wenn man es auf Österreichisches Deutsch beziehen wollte - wohl eher eine Eigenheit der Donaumonarchie, vor allem der böhmischen und ungarischen Landesteile. Der "brave Soldat Schwejk" mit Fritz Muliar lebt geradezu von diesen Fehlern.

Comment: Wer braucht schon Akkusativ?! :-) Auch ein schönes Bsp.: "Kommst du mal bei die Oma!"

Answer (score 1):

Es ist ein Fehler, klingt sehr ungebildet, und wird von starken Dialektsprechern verschiedenster Regionen verwendet. "Erlaubt" würde ich nicht sagen, eher verpönt.

Comment: D.h sich dialektal auszudrücken wäre also immer als ungebildet aufgefasst?

Comment: nein, aber bei diesem schon. Grober Grammatikfehler. Es gibt auch akzeptierte Dialekteigenheiten der Grammatik, so etwas aber nicht.

Comment: Das ist  ja meine Frage: ist dies auch im Mundart und Umgangssprachlich etwas das Leute stützig macht?

Comment: Leichter Dialekt ist OK, krasser Dialekt kommt immer ungebildet herüber.